# Give me better idea to do Marquee tag in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, html, css, marquee

The bellow code working, but i don’t know it the write way or not?

```
<td align="center" style=" height:50px; width:100%;  background-color:Red;width:10%;">

<div id="divremview" >

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">

<div id="div1"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Hi</asp:Label></div>

</marquee>

</div>    </td>
```

Also it not in center alignment. As usual it in left alignment

Comment: this just beeds to be re-tagged from asp.net to html and css

Comment: "The code below is working, but i don’t know if it the right way or not?"

Typo fix

Comment: Why do you have two widths on the first column? 100% and 10%? Also is there any style defined for the divremview?

Comment: I thought that marquee tags were pretty much deprecated

Comment: @Eric:  You're right - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: any other way to use the marquee...

Comment: i think the better question is why would you want to use a marquee?  theres a reason it's deprecated :)

Comment: Don't use marquee and other annoying, unnecessary, outdated, outmoded, trashy, flashy, naive, unsupported, distorting, overstimulating, overachieving tags.

Comment: Well, when CSS3 is fully-functional, this functionality will be back in action with properties such as `marquee-direction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `marquee` control is a IE only control and has been deprecated long time ago.
I suggest you to look at other standard alternatives like a jQuery plug-in.

Examples:

- [jQuery news ticker](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)
- [jQuery liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)