# What ASP.NET tag to scroll an image like a <marquee> tag in HTML?

Tags: asp.net

I want scroll an image as like marquee tag in HTML. what the tag in ASP .Net  (if any) to scroll a Image ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you provide some code, with expected results?

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Read again. it's a pretty simple question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The phrase "navigate a image" makes no sense. One cannot navigate an image "like a marquee". :S

Comment: @BernhardHofmann _navigate a image as like marquee tag_ it's very simple to understand.(IMO) he wants the image to scroll from right to left ( or left to right).

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have no idea what this question means either. If you do, it would be helpful if you could edit the question in such a way that others can understand it too. (Seeing your edited comment, I can see that the OP probably does mean that, thanks for that.)

Comment: _scroll an image_ makes more sense. (cpu should not be 100% in order to understand it).

Comment: There is no mqrquee tag in asp.net . you can use this however - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821131/give-me-better-idea-to-do-marquee-tag-in-asp-net-page

Comment: how about using a marquee tag, and inside it put your asp image tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use @keyframes or animation. That will work like marquee tag or more simpler than any marquee property. We can even control the scroll property of any image. We only have to do one thing. We have to put an image in a div and use the @keyframes on the image container div. It's is more simpler than marquee.